# How deallocation of memory in vector of vector

Tags: c++11

I have a dynamic vector of vector: `vector< vector <CelMap> > cels` where CelMap is an object of type class, 
and i need to free the memory. How can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to free the memory?", that is really imprecise.   Upon going out of scope `cels` will invoke it's destructor, and in turn destructors of all contained objects. Also, maybe a nit picky but there is no "static" `vector`, `std::vector` is `std::vector.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) - that, if granted, will reduce the allocated memory to the exact memory the vector is occupying at that moment.

Vectors will allocate more memory than they use which can be inspected with [capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) and increased with [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

[shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) is a request to reduce the allocated memory to the actual vector size and it's granting is implementation dependent,

> Requests the removal of unused capacity. It is a non-binding request
>   to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation if
>   the request is fulfilled.